# How can I make this faster? Do I need dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble to execute this example without good packages to big data. I am providing a simple example, but in real I am doing that for a table with more than 4 millions rows and 150 columns.

```
library(stringr)
a<-c(1,"1_2_3_1_2_3_1")
b<-c(1,"2_2_2_3_3_3_3")
c<-c(1,"3_3_3_3_3_3_3")
df<-rbind(a,b,c)

m1<-str_split_fixed(df[,2], "_", 7)

a<-list()
for(i in 1:nrow(m1)){
  a[[i]]<-sort(unique(m1[i,]))
  df[i,2]<-paste(a[[i]],collapse=" ")}
```

How can I make this faster? I know that dplyr can help me, but I had found just advices for to remove based on row and not column.

the expected result is df. the situation is that I need to remove the duplicates of states of df [,1] in order to return the unique states of df [,1]. In my real situation my states are words instead of numbers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the outcome that you are expecting and provide the expected result for your 3 row example. `c<-c(1,"3_3_3_3_3_3_3")` returns a character vector and `df<-rbind(a,b,c)` creates a character matrix.

Comment: so this, `df[,2] <- sapply(strsplit(df[,2], '_'), function(i) paste0(unique(i), collapse = '_'))`?

Comment: @Sotos change to `collapse = " "` and post it as an answer so the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: the expected result is df. the situation is that I need to remove the duplicates of states of df [,1] in order to return the unique states of df [,1]. In my real situation my states are words instead of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more R-ish way to do this (rather than using a for-loop), is to use `sapply` directly on your variable after splitting it.

```
df[,2] <- sapply(strsplit(df[,2], '_'), function(i) paste0(unique(i), collapse = '_'))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   [,1] [,2]   
> a "1"  "1_2_3"
> b "1"  "2_3"  
> c "1"  "3"
> ```

Comparing these two solutions with `microbenchmark` gives us:

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr  min     lq      mean     median  uq      max      neval
      sotos 106.635 112.794 116.3727 115.489 119.338 229.822  1000
      op    275.632 283.716 288.9455 288.336 292.185 440.010  1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Is that benchmark of a larger data frame?

Comment: Yes. I made a larger dataframe like this: `df <- do.call("rbind", replicate(10, df, simplify = FALSE))`